# Will the single resource in try with resource statement be not closed if there is an exception thrown from the statement (initialization issue)

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Example code:

```
    class TestCharStream {
        public static void main(String[] args){
// Assume specified file is not available in the location
            try (Reader reader = new FileReader("C:\\TestData\\test123.txt")) {
                System.out.println("Entered Try block");
                int content;
                while ((content = reader.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.print((char) content);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

As the file is not available, there will be'FileNotFoundException' thrown and resource will be failed to initialize.

From Java SE7 spec, I understand the below points relating to 'try with resources' statement

- If a resource fails to initialize (that is, its initializer expression throws an exception), then all resources initialized so far by the try-with-resources statement are closed.
- A resource is closed only if it initialized to a non-null value.
- If exceptions are thrown from both the try block and the try-with-resources statement,  then the method  throws the exception thrown from the try block; the exception thrown from the try-with-resources statement is suppressed.

I have questions relating to closing resources, suppressing exceptions relating to the points specified above

1) Does the above example code case (i.e. resource failed to initialize) not fall under the scenario *..resource will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly*. Is this applicable only for resources initialized successfully in try with resources statement and there is an error in the try block?

2) If exceptions are thrown while initializing resources(like the example), this will fall under unsuccessful initialization scenario. In this case, how do we come across the scenario of exceptions thrown in a try-with-resources statement (which could basically occur only during initialization) at all?  Is it the exceptions thrown while closing the resource?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1) Does the above example code case (i.e. resource failed to
>   initialize) not fall under the scenario ..*resource will be closed
>   regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or
>   abruptly*. Is this applicable only for resources initialized
>   successfully in try with resources statement and there is an error in
>   the try block?

It's unclear what you're referencing with "resource will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly".  Nevertheless, if attempted initialization of a resource in the resource specification throws an exception then no, that resource is not closed, because it was not initialized to a non-null value (your second bullet point, which is an excerpt from the JLS text).

If there were multiple resources in the resource specification, then it would be possible for some to be initialized before initialization of one of them throws; in that case, the ones that were successfully initialized to non-null values are closed.

> 2) If exceptions are thrown while initializing resources(like the
>   example), this will fall under unsuccessful initialization scenario.
>   In this case, how do we come across the scenario of exceptions thrown
>   in a try-with-resources statement (which could basically occur only
>   during initialization) at all? Is it the exceptions thrown while
>   closing the resource?

A try-with-resources statement is a compound statement, encompassing everything from the initial `try` keyword, though the associated block, and including any `catch` and and `finally` clauses.  The primary focus is on cleaning up correctly in the event of an exception thrown from inside the `try` block.  The bits in the specification about cases where an exception occurs during resource initialization can be understood in terms of the equivalency between an *N*-resource try-with-resources statement and *N* nested single-resource try-with-resources statements.

Note, too, that the JLS presents [a translation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1) of a try-with-resources statement into equivalent code using traditional `try` / `catch` / `finally` and explicit resource closure.  That would be a good resource to consider if you are struggling with the semantics of try-with-resources.

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. It helps. 3 more follow up questions to clarify: 

1) Exercpt from JLS-  catch clauses and a finally clause are often unnecessary when resources are closed automatically. But in my example, there is a possibility of IOException while reading the character stream.
In that case, if we do not handle it - the code does not get compiled. Hence we have to surround it with respective catch block.
So, the generic statement in JLS saying the catch and finally clauses often unnecessary(at least catch clause) confuses me little bit. Did I get it wrong?

Comment: 2) "A try-with-resources statement is a compound statement..". So, in my example the try with resources statement comprises resource initialization in parentheses, associated block and the following catch clause. Correct? [PS:Even in official Java pages, we see try-with-reources statement and try block as separate terms. This confused me little bit.]

Comment: 3) In the example which I quoted where the resource is not initialized successfully, as the resource will not be closed automatically - 
If there is a catch block to handle it ( which I have in my example), it will be handled as a regular try-catch
Else, the program terminates. Correct?

Comment: @sake, (1) you do not need catch block on the try-with-resources.  You have the alternative of declaring that the method throws the exception, or of catching the exception inside the method but outside the try-with-resources.  Additionally, some resource types may implement a `close()` that does not declare any checked exceptions.

Comment: @sake, (2) yes, in your example, the try-with-resources starts with the `try` keyword and contains everything from there to the end of the `catch` block.  This is pretty clear from [the BNF representation in the JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3). I'm not sure what other documentation you're looking at that is confusing you, but the JLS is definitive in such matters.

Comment: @sake, (3) more or less.  More precisely, given a try-with-resources statement that has associated `catch` and / or `finally` blocks, if one of the resource initializations throws then the exception will be handled by the first matching `catch`, if any, and control will enter the `finally` block before it leaves the statement.  If there is no matching `catch` or if the exception is re-thrown, then it can still be handled by a standard `try` / `catch` that is in dynamic scope, but if it isn't handled then it will cause the thread to die, and maybe the whole application.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes. If the resources are initialized successfully and if the try block has an exception, the resources will be closed just like we will in the finally block without try with resource.

2) The documentation says(little modified):

> Without try with resource, If in a method, both read() and close() (in finally block) throw exceptions, then the method throws the exception thrown from the finally block; the exception thrown from the try block is suppressed. In contrast, with try with resource, if exceptions are thrown from both the try block and the try-with-resources statement, then the method throws the exception thrown from the try block; the exception thrown from the try-with-resources block is suppressed.

As you mentioned, the exception from try-with-resource in second point will be from closing the resources.

Answer (score 0):

The *try-with-resources* is syntactic sugar over old syntax and writing it using the old syntax may help you understand what it does:

This kind of example:

```
  try (AutoCloseable ac1 = ac1(); AutoCloseable ac2 = ac2()) {
    ac2.doWhatever();
  } catch (Exception e) { 
    fail(e);
  }
```

Is rewritten like this:

```
  AutoCloseable ac1 = null;
  try {
    ac1 = ac1();
    AutoCloseable ac2 = null;
    try {
      ac2 = ac2();
      ac2.doWhatever();
    } catch (Exception e) { 
      fail(e);
    } finally {
      if (ac2 != null) ac2.close();
    }
  } catch (Exception e) { 
    fail(e);
  } finally {
    if (ac1 != null) ac1.close();
  }
```

The compiler will probably optimize the code:

- there can be only one finally block and it'll probably merge the two.
- use some synthetic function to handle the catch which is the same.

If you are interested, this [presentation by E. Mandrikov](https://youtu.be/xKRNbQsGavI?t=550) explains what the compiler does and how it is a headache for code coverage.

As you can see, it may fail in the initialization part:

- `ac1` initialization may fail and in that case, the variable would be `null` (default value).
- `ac2` initialization may fail, `ac1` would not be null.
- `ac1` and `ac2` may work, and in that case, only the `doWhatever()` would be responsible for failing.

If `ac2` depends on `ac1`, and is not in the list of resource, eg:

```
try (AutoCloseable ac2 = ac2(ac1())) {
  ...
}
```

Then, the `AutoCloseable` build by `ac1()` won't get closed unless it is closed in `ac2::close`. And the garbage collector won't call `ac1::close`.